# Counting Character of jwysiwyg text editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rich-text-editor

I am trying to set maximum character length for an [jwysiwyg](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg) text editor.

I tried to use .keyup function. But its not working. I am using

```
dwr.util.getValue("jwysiwyg") //Its a dwr utility to get the value of an element.
```

to get the content of the text editor.
jwysiwyg is the id of text area. Its working.

But if i try to use the same id like,

```
$("#jwysiwyg").keyup(this.countChars);
```

Its not working.

Is there any other way to get the .keyup event of an text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$("#jwysiwyg").keyup(function(){
  return dwr.util.getValue("jwysiwyg").length;  // or try ur code here this.countChars(if length doesnt work)
});
```